# Python code for matching a string in a file

Tags: python

I want to match a string in a file but the string contains new line, Is there any way to execute it?
I mean I want to match

"y
t"

in
"py
thon"

I tried this code:

```
def ffindstring(fname, s):
file1 = open(fname, "r")
# opening file in read mode
f = 0
for line in file1:
    if s in line:
        # checking the presence of string in each line of file
        f = 1
        break
if f == 0:
    return False
else:
    return True
file1.close()
```

but I did not get the output as True if I check
"y
t"  as input string in a file contains

"py
thon"

file new_file.txt contains:

```
py
thon

ruby
perl
```

ffindstring("new_file.txt","y\nt")
It returns False,but it should be True

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share the code you tried and explain what didn't work. (as part of the edited question, not as a comment)

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `li:str=" "` and `li+=i`. Do you want to search for the full string `s` right from start or does your search string build up incrementally? In the latter you have missed indentation after `li+=i` and wrong initialization in `li:str=" "`.

Comment: I removed li from the code, but still not working as I expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the whole file at once and concatenate the list into a string.

```
def ffindstring(fname, s):
    with open(fname) as f: 
        lines = f.readlines()
    
    return True if s in ''.join(lines) else False
```

Comment: Note, that your solution will ignore _newlines_ when searching. This means if searched for `s = 'py\nthon'`, it might be in a multiline file, but __is not__ `in ''.join(['py', 'thon'])` and returns false.

Answer (score 2):

`for line in file1` reads one line at a time, e.g. `'py\n'`, `'thon\n'`, so you can't match a string that is more than one line. Read the file as a whole string by `f.read()` instead, like `'py\nthon\n\nruby\nperl\n'` and check whether `s` is in this string.

```
def ffindstring(fname, s):
    # with open is preferred as it will close the file for you after operation
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        if s in f.read():
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(ffindstring("test.txt", "y\nt")) # Output: True
```

Comment: I would prefer this [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=newline#io.TextIOBase.read) solution (read all text from file at once), because it allows to search for multi-line text exactly. Means it is a difference if searching for `'python'` (without line-breaks) or for `'py\nthon'` (with newline inside).